# Radio Buttons and Check Boxes not sent in query string or post body when blank form is submitted

Tags: html, forms, servlets, form-submit, fiddler

I've following form

```
<form method="post" action="getParameterValuesServlet">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="userName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hobbies</td>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="cycling">Cycling<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="swimming">Swimming<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="treking">Treking<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>
                <select name="city" multiple>
                    <option value="mysore">Mysore</option>
                    <option value="pune">Pune</option>
                    <option value="chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When I submit this form without entering or selecting any values, I see only blank userName and password (text & password) in post body (same is the case with GET query string)

Why don't radio button, check box and drop down values get submitted with default values?

One more thing, if I remove "multiple" attribute from "select" tag, the first option gets submitted.

Would be thankful, if someone explains this behavior!!

FYI, I'm using Fiddler Web Debugger tool to trace the request and response and submitting this form to a Java Servlet

Answer (score 0):

What *default values* do you imagine would be sent?

The only values that get sent are the selected options; since no options are selected, there's nothing to send.

That's in contrast to `text` and `password` controls, which always have a value, even if that value is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden field with a fallback value, if a checkbox in a form is submitted unchecked:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hobbies" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbies" value="swimming">Swimming<br>
```

This seems to work also with radio buttons:

```
<input type="hidden" name="gender" value="">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
```